# Error loading background image into JPanel in a JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, imageicon

I have a `JFrame` in which I want to occupy it entirely with a `JPanel` and put a background image in the `JPanel`.

**Code:**

```
public class InicioSesion extends javax.swing.JFrame{
private Image imagenFondo;
private URL fondo;

public InicioSesion(){
    initComponents();
    try{
        fondo = this.getClass().getResource("fondo.jpg");
        imagenFondo = ImageIO.read(fondo);
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print("Image dont load"); //Dont load the message.
    }

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.add(PanelFondo);
}

public JPanel panelFondo = new JPanel(){
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(imagenFondo, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
};
```

**Why doesn't the image load? Any solution to my code?**

[image]

Comment: I would change `imagenFondo = new ImageIcon(fondo).getImage();` to `imgenFondo = ImageIO.read(fondo);`

Comment: I would also add a `super.paintComponent(g);` as the first line of my paintComponent override, and would check that the image isn't null before painting it within this method.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter Thanks for your answer but i have the same error. Edit question with the new code.

Comment: What error? Is your code throwing an exception?

Comment: Check the new code

Comment: Also, what on earth does `initComponents();` do? Are you changing the contentPane's layout manager? Perhaps the image is being added to the JPanel but the JPanel is too small to be seen since the contentPane's layout manager might not allow for expansion of the JPanel within the GUI. You need to create and post a valid [mre]. Normally the components are added to the JPanel with the image -- we don't see you doing this at all.

Comment: initComponents() in Java Swing is vital to load all the elements when starting the JFrame program. The image has a normal size to be loaded, neither large nor small.

Comment: You don't understand -- initComponents is adding things to the contentPane but not your background image. Yes the "image" is normal size, but the JPanel that draws it likely is quite small, probably 0,0. Again, you need to add your GUI components to the drawing JPanel, which you're currently not doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
initComponents();
```

You likely add all components to the GUI in this method, quite possibly using GroupLayout or other user-unfriendly layout manager, and then add the `panelFondo` JPanel after all components have been added.

If you want a GUI to show a background image, the components need to be added to the image-drawing JPanel, and if any JPanels are added on top of the image drawer, they need to be transparent (setOpaque(false)`) so that the background image shows through.

---

I'm guessing that you're using a GUI builder to create your GUI layouts and to assist you in adding components to the GUI. Myself, I avoid using them and much prefer creating my GUI's by hand using layout managers (never null layouts). If you absolutely must use a GUI builder, then have the builder create a JPanel for you, not a JFrame, and then override this JPanel's paintComponent, drawing the image within it. Otherwise you may be better off learning the Swing layout managers and creating your GUI's by hand like I do.

Your window appears to be a sign-in window, and if so, if this were my program, I wouldn't even use a JFrame but rather a *modal* JDialog to display this since it would be much easier to control program flow in this way.

---

Proof of concept program using GridBagLayout and way too many "magic numbers":

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginPanel extends JPanel {
    public static final String TITLE = "INICIO DE SESIÓN";
    public static final String IMG_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/"
            + "commons/thumb/6/69/MarsSunset.jpg/779px-MarsSunset.jpg";
    private JTextField usuarioField = new JTextField(20);
    private JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);
    private BufferedImage backgroundImg = null;

    public LoginPanel(BufferedImage img) {
        this.backgroundImg = img;
        JCheckBox showPasswordChkBx = new JCheckBox("Show Password");
        showPasswordChkBx.setOpaque(false);
        showPasswordChkBx.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    passwordField.setEchoChar((char) 0);
                } else {
                    passwordField.setEchoChar('*');
                }
            }
        });

        JButton accederBtn = new JButton("Acceder");
        accederBtn.addActionListener(e -> {
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(LoginPanel.this);
            win.dispose();
        });

        setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        int row = 0;

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        int ins = 12;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(ins, ins, ins, ins);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(TITLE);
        titleLabel.setFont(titleLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 24f));
        add(titleLabel, gbc);

        row++;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        add(new JLabel("Usuario:"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        add(usuarioField, gbc);

        row++;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(ins, ins, 0, ins);
        add(new JLabel("Password:"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        add(passwordField, gbc);

        row++;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, ins, ins, ins);
        add(new JLabel(""), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        add(showPasswordChkBx, gbc);

        row++;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(ins, ins, ins, ins);
        add(new JLabel(""), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        add(accederBtn, gbc);

    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuarioField.getText();
    }

    public char[] getPassword() {
        return passwordField.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (backgroundImg != null) {
            g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSize = super.getPreferredSize();
        int width = superSize.width;
        int height = superSize.height;
        if (backgroundImg != null) {
            width = Math.max(width, backgroundImg.getWidth());
            height = Math.max(height, backgroundImg.getHeight());
        }
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            URL imgUrl = new URL(IMG_PATH);
            img = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        LoginPanel mainPanel = new LoginPanel(img);
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog((JFrame) null, LoginPanel.TITLE, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.add(mainPanel);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println("User Name: " + mainPanel.getUsuario());
        System.out.println("Password: " + new String(mainPanel.getPassword()));
    }
}
```

Comment: So... ¿What is the solution in my case?

Comment: @omaza1990: again, as mentioned above, add the GUI components to the JPanel that does the background painting. The *specific* solution is impossible to give you without your posting [mre] program code in your question.

Comment: I'm not so expert at designing Component GUIs -JPanel, etc... myself

Comment: @omaza1990: The tutorials are not hard, and they are not difficult to learn, and they do offer you the best solution to your current problem.

Comment: JFrame is the main window and all other .java files have to be JDialog

Comment: @omaza1990: correct, and since this is a login-window, it is *not* the main window.

Comment: Perfect but although I have changed it to JDialog your modification doesn't work for me to show the image in the background of the JPanel

Comment: Some elements are behind the background image. Can the JPanel image be made transparent?

Comment: @omaza1990: don't go that route not when using a background image, and Swing GUI rendering can get weird when dealing with semi-transparent components. Instead, put the components on the drawing JPanel itself. Please see my code example above, which incidentally uses a modal JDialog.