# JPanel transparent background and display elements

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I insert a **background imag**e into a `JPanel` but some interface elements disappear. The following Java Swing elements do not appear:

- label_titulo
- label_usuario
- label_password
- button_acceder

**Can you make the image transparent or that the elements are not opaque (setOpaque (false)), even putting it to those elements does not work for me.

Why do some elements have rectangles encapsulating them in gray?**

**Code:**

```
public class InicioSesion extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    private Image imagenFondo;
    private URL fondo;

    public InicioSesion(){
        initComponents();

        try{
            fondo = this.getClass().getResource("fondo.jpg");
            imagenFondo = ImageIO.read(fondo);
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("Imagen no cargada.");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(imagenFondo, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
}
```

When loading "RUN" the .java file appears to me as follows:

[image]

Originally the design is as follows:

[image]

Comment: A login screen is better implemented with a JDialog, rather than a JFrame.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Right, I just changed it.

Comment: Why did you even ask this question? You already have an answer from your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61851372/error-loading-background-image-into-jpanel-in-a-jframe. Why are you wasting our time by changing the code to do painting on the frame instead of the JPanel?

Answer (score 2):

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(imagenFondo, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
}
```

Don't override paint(). The paint method is responsible for painting the child components. So your code paints the child components and then draws the image over top of the components.

Instead, for custom painting of a component you override the `paintComponent()` method of a `JPanel`:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(imagenFondo, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
}
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorail on [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) for more information.

Edit:

Read the entire section from the Swing tutorial on `Custom Painting`. The solution is to do the custom painting on a JPanel and then add the panel to the frame.

The content pane of a frame is a JPanel. So you will in effect be replacing the default content pane with your custom JPanel that paints the background image. Set the layout of your custom panel to a `BorderLayout` and it will work just like the default content pane.

Comment: @camickr Error: super.paintComponent(g); cannot symbol found

Comment: @camick So.. What method do I have to use? paint(Graphics g) or paintComponent(Graphics g)

Comment: @omaza1990, I did not notice you are extending JFrame your question only talks about a JPanel. For custom painting you should NOT extend JFrame. Custom painting is done on a Swing component, in your case a `JPanel`. See edit.

Comment: Glad it helped. Even though this is the same answer you received in your last question, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem is solved.

Comment: Why do you closed the question?

Comment: 1) The question has been answered. 2) you already got the same answer in your previous question. So there is no need to keep posting the same question when you already have an answer.

Comment: It is a different question. In this case, I have a problem trying to replace an element of a panel with another element.

Comment: No, this question is about painting a background image on a panel and adding components to the panel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214130/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-camickr).

Comment: What is there to discuss? Your topic title is about a `JPanel`. So I provided you with an answer on how to paint properly on a JPanel. I then realized your code was actually using a JFrame, not a panel, so I clarified the answer and provided you with a link to the Swing tutorial which contains a complete example. Later I realize you already had a working example from a question a day earlier. You have been given plenty of information on how to paint a background image on a panel and add components to the same panel.